# How can we access nested object using n1ql by applying filter to object name

Tags: couchbase, sql++

Sample JSON:

```
{
   "id":"idValue",
   "rank":{
      "1":{
         "city":"Mumbai"
      },
      "2":{
         "city":"Delhi"
      }
   },
   "KEY":"RANK"
}
```

Expected result: get the document max rank city where "KEY"="RANK"

```
[
   {
      "id":"idValue",
      "city":"Delhi"
   }
]
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    b.id,  
    (SELECT p.val 
     FROM OBJECT_PAIRS(b.rank) p 
     WHERE `p`.`name` = (SELECT to_string(MAX(TONUMBER(v))) 
                         FROM OBJECT_NAMES(b.rank) v)) 
FROM 
    `rating` b 
WHERE 
    b.KEY = 'RANK'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.id,
       (SELECT RAW MAX([TONUMBER(op.name) , op.val])[1]
        FROM OBJECT_PAIRS(b.`rank`) AS op)[0].*
FROM mybucket AS b
WHERE b.`KEY` = "RANK";
```

OR

```
SELECT b.id, b.`rank`.[name].city
FROM mybucket AS b
LET name = TO_STR(ARRAY_MAX(ARRAY TONUMBER(n) FOR n:v IN b.`rank` END))
WHERE b.`KEY` = "RANK";
```